# how to implement the Smartsheet API client-side code using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, smartsheet-api, client-side-scripting

"Could you please guide me on how to implement the Smartsheet API client-side code using Browserify? I am trying to use the Smartsheet API in my web application, and I am not sure how to proceed with the client-side implementation. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you."

I would like to provide some context in this matter. I have an HTML page that enables users to submit their comments/feedback, and upon submission, it updates the Smartsheet sheet. Additionally, it is imperative that I utilize the HTML page for this purpose, and no alternative options are permitted.

These are the steps I have attempted so far.
step 0. Installation of required libraries e.g smartsheet ,browserify

Step 1. Created main.js file with following code.

```
const client = require('smartsheet');
const smartsheet = client.createClient({
  accessToken: 'secret token', 
  logLevel: 'info'
}); 
//module.exports = smartsheet;  
global.window.smartsheet = smartsheet;
```

Step 2. Create a bundle

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Step 3. refer the bundle.js in html page

```
<script src="./lib/bundle.js"></script>
```

Step 4. add following function in the script file

```
function updateSmartsheet(){    
    // Check if the smartsheet variable is defined
    const smartsheet = window.smartsheet;
    
    // Set queryParameters for `include` and pagination
    var options = {
      queryParameters: {
        include: "attachments",
        includeAll: true
      }
    };

    // List all sheets
    smartsheet.sheets.listSheets(options) //program exits with TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
      .then(function (result) {
        var sheetId = result.data[0].id;                

        // Load one sheet
        smartsheet.sheets.getSheet({id: sheetId})
          .then(function(sheetInfo) {
            console.log(sheetInfo);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    

  }
```

getting following error at this line  smartsheet.sheets.listSheets(options)

```
bundle.js:58387 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at exports.Console.Console.log (bundle.js:58387)
    at transportLog (bundle.js:57729)
    at bundle.js:42474
    at eachOfArrayLike (bundle.js:40433)
    at eachOf (bundle.js:40481)
    at Object.eachLimit (bundle.js:42536)
    at exports.Logger.Logger.log (bundle.js:57741)
    at logRequestBasics (bundle.js:53943)
    at Object.logRequest (bundle.js:53910)
    at methodRequest (bundle.js:53836)
    at Object.get (bundle.js:53793)
    at Object.listSheets (bundle.js:52964)
    at updateSmartsheet (Dummy.js:160)
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance anyone can provide in this matter. I have limited experience with JavaScript.

Comment: I've added the [browserify] tag to your question so that folks with expertise in that product can chime in.

Comment: I think I can try this as well https://dev.to/gbudjeakp/how-to-connect-your-client-side-to-your-server-side-using-node-and-express-2i71

Comment: This is the solution https://dev.to/gbudjeakp/how-to-connect-your-client-side-to-your-server-side-using-node-and-express-2i71 . let me know if someone has any better suggestions.